# how to use group_concat for some data like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with the following data in MySQL:

if table has four record.

```
id   color
1    red
2    blue
3    yellow
4    pink
```

then i want result like

```
id  color
1   red, blue, yellow & pink
```

if table have two record then

```
id   color
1    red
2    pink
```

then i want result like

```
id  color
1   red & pink
```

i want this result using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by concatenating the string and the taking the first "n - 1" elements and adding in the last one:

```
select concat(substring_index(list, ', ', cnt - 1), ' & ',
              substring_index(list, ', ', -1)  
             )               
from (select group_concat(color separator ', ') as list, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Note:  You need additional logic if the table could have only one row.

Comment: but what if only one color is there